# What does "We have the needle in this state, and we use it" mean?

Tags: phrases, idioms, american-english

In the Stephen King novel, so the cop says to the guy who is yet proven to be guilty:

> "Right now you're going to jail. And guess what? We have the needle in
>   this state, and we use it."

Could you please  elaborate.

Comment: Hello, Sai Kiran. Thanks for your question. Unfortunately, without more context, it is impossible to say how the author intended "we got a needle in the state" to be understood. If you include more of the surrounding dialogue, it might be possible to identify what sense of _needle_ the author had in mind. One source that I checked says that _needle_ in the sense of "annoyance , nettling, or vexation" is "usu. constr. with _give the_, _get the_, etc."—but again, there is too little information in your question as it is currently formulated to say whether that sense of _needle_ is intended.

Comment: Sai Kiran, if you're asking what something means, it's vital you quote the exact words; "we got needle in the state" is not the same as "We have the needle in this state". I'll edit your question so that the errors are removed and your question can be more accurately answered. PS the image of the page is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing "the needle" is a metonym that refers to the death penalty by lethal injection. This is supported by the context of criminal activity in the passage.

Comment: Yep - have read this book, and agree fully that it is about lethal injection.