# What is the difference in meaning between "get back to him" and "get back at him"?

Tags: idioms, prepositions, american-english, phrasal-verbs

> And you were afraid that if you started asking questions, it would **get back to** him
> <sub>From *[The Outsider](https://books.google.it/books?id=uiVHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT124&dq=%22%20if%20you%20started%20asking%20questions,%20it%20would%20get%20back%20to%20him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOyrKMtb3fAhXC7YMKHZsPDjkQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22%20if%20you%20started%20asking%20questions%2C%20it%20would%20get%20back%20to%20him%22&f=false)* by Stephen King</sub>

I know that to [“*get back* **at** *someone*”](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-back-at-someone) is similar to humiliate or to wreak revenge.
*Cambridge Dictionary* says

> to punish someone because that person has done something wrong to you:
>
> - *I think he’s trying to get back at her for what she said in the meeting.*

Furthermore, the expression “[*get your own back* ***on*** *someone*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-your-own-back-on-sb?q=get%20your%20own%20back%20%28on%20sb%29https://)” shares a very similar meaning

> to do something unpleasant to someone because they have done something unpleasant to you
>
> - *I'll get my own back on her one day.*

But I do not understand why the meaning of “to” used in “**get back to**” does not share a similar meaning. Revenge is in the direction of (“to”) someone. I feel that the three phrasal verbs: *“get back at”*, *“get your own back on someone”* and *“get back to”* have very similar meanings. But in the quotation taken from Stephen King's novel, the meaning is clearly different.

**Questions**

1. Why does “get back to someone” have a different meaning from “get back **at** someone” and “get your own back **on** someone”?
2. Why should such a small word like “to” make such a great difference?

Comment: Your title says "get back **at** him". Your screenshot shows "get back **to** him". Not the same thing.

Comment: Sai Kiran, you posted [a similar question recently](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/478040) which was put on hold for not showing any evidence of research. I am flagging this question for closure for exactly the same reason. Please read [ask] and take the EL&U [Tour] so that you understand what's expected on our site.

Comment: I also think your questions might be better received at [ell.se]. That site was created for questions like this one.

Comment: @J.R. would you mind casting your vote to reopen this question? The migration failed, and the reopening process flopped in the reviews. (??) Maybe you could ask the mods on EL&U to migrate the post. With a little TLC, I think the question has merits.

Comment: Well, this question is much different from the one I initially responded to. I think I've already addressed the differences in meaning, and I don't think there's much that can (or should) be said about why small words can make big differences - this is one of the weird features of language use, after all, and not just in English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think you should post your own question instead of editing so radically.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think this question would have merits on ELL, the forum that was created to handle learner questions like this one. To me, this looks like another learner who strayed onto ELU and (mistakenly?) thought this was the place to ask questions like _"What is the difference between “get back **to** someone” and “get back **at** someone”?_ – a question that might easily vex a learner yet most sixth-graders could probably explain without consulting a dictionary. But maybe I'm just old-school about that – from what I've observed, it seems like this community is content to be ELL II.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I post plenty of questions on my own, but sometimes a question that can seem banal, and too easy can be useful for non-native speakers. In the spirit of helping learners, new contributors, and ultimately, the whole community, it is better to edit and fix a question in order to encourage better answers than to have it lying away on a heap.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - One other advantage to fixing up a question as you did here is that it can provide a pattern for the newer user to follow when asking future questions. Had you merely asked the revised question on your own, it's unlikely the OP would ever see it.

Answer (score 4):

- To *get back **at*** someone usually means to take revenge on them.
- To *get back **to*** someone usually means to resume an earlier conversation with them. Example: "I'll check if we have enough food for dinner and get back to you on whether we should get more groceries."
- In the Stephen King quote posted by OP, the usage is a version of the phrase *word will get (back) to* someone. This refers to that someone indirectly finding out about what was originally said without them knowing. So another way of interpreting what the speaker is saying in the underlined text is this: "And you were afraid that if you started asking questions, he would eventually find out."

Answer (score 1):

Here's the 4th explanation on Collins Dictionary:

> 4. **phrasal verb** (*informal*)
>      If you get back at someone or get them back, you do something unpleasant to them in order to have revenge for something unpleasant that they did to you.

Hope this may help.